# PHP header location not working- working in xampp

Tags: php, redirect, header

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Location redirect test page</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
header('Location: http://www.google.com');
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I uploaded this code to my server(1 and 1). Its not redirecting. I used the same code in XAMPP and it worked fine. 
What am I doing wrong? Why is it working on xampp and not on real (1and1) server? I appreciate any help. 
Thank you

Comment: http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: there is no way this would work anywhere considering you're echoing / displaying code above `header` which is not allowed...

Comment: Output the header at the top of your script; also, the HTML variant needs a `<meta http-equiv="refresh">` tag as well.

Comment: @webeno It would be fine if OP were using `ob_start()` or implicit output buffering is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not call header function after output. it shows warning as "header already sent...".
you must write it before  tag.

```html
<?php 
header('Location: http://www.google.com');
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Location redirect test page</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

*may be your server setting for showing warning is off so it wont display warnings to you on related server.

Comment: I have to write my whole code over again. I wrote everything while testing on Xampp. I have many "header-locations" throughout the pages. using php code before html worked on 1and1 server. Thank you!!!!

Comment: if you have multiple redirection statement in page then use javascript[window.location.href] instead of PHP [header("Location:")].

Answer (score 1):

If by some reason you can't place the php snippet before the html code (like Mayur said) you can use JavaScript for redirects

```
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

**Remember that when setting headers from php or setting cookies no text must be out putted before the php command!**